# The import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException cannot be resolved

Tags: java, java-11

I just migrated a java project from JDK8 to JDK11.

The project implements Maven dependecy management.
The IDE I'm using is Eclipse jee-2018-12.
Java version: Dcevm-11 on Trava OpenJDK.

I can't find how to resolve this dependencies:

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;

I think I should add a dependency in my pom.xml but I have no clue.

Has anyone fronted this same problem?

Thank you,
Giacomo

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/52568117/545127

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm posting the solution because I hope it'll be useful for someone with my same problem.

I have to say this project agglomerates a lot of small projects with a resulting long list of dependencies.

Investigating maven dependencies, I've found out that a library needed for some print reports (batik) had old xml-apis dependencies.

By excluding these dependencies from Dependency Hierarchy view on my pom.xml within Eclipse, I fixed the problem.

So: pom.xml -> Maven editor -> Dependency Hierarchy -> watch for conflicts -> exclude them

Giacomo.